# Implementing C11 threads for windows

Tags: c, winapi, pthreads

I have a header file for thread creation with pthreads (C11). Now I want to create another header which can be chosen for Windows operating systems (WIN32). I am currently struggling a bit to get started, mostly because it is a requirement to keep function signatures, and I do not understand how to deal with this. Here is my problem:

C11 header snippet:

```
/* types */
typedef pthread_t thrd_t;
typedef pthread_mutex_t mtx_t;
typedef pthread_cond_t cnd_t;
typedef pthread_key_t tss_t;
typedef pthread_once_t once_flag;

typedef int (*thrd_start_t)(void*);
typedef void (*tss_dtor_t)(void*);

static inline int thrd_create(thrd_t *thr, thrd_start_t func, void *arg)
{
    return pthread_create(thr, 0, (void*(*)(void*))func, arg) == 0 ? thrd_success : thrd_error;
}
```

WIN32 (what I have so far):

```
/* types */
typedef HANDLE thrd_t;

static inline int thrd_create(thrd_t *thr, thrd_start_t func, void *arg)
{
    thrd_t = CreateThread(
          _In_      SIZE_T                 dwStackSize,
          _In_      LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
          _In_      DWORD                  dwCreationFlags,
        );
    return pthread_create(thr, 0, (void*(*)(void*))func, arg) == 0 ? thrd_success : thrd_error;
}
```

I have intentionally pasted the signature of CreateThread() to explain my problem: How do I use my inputs `(thrd_t *thr, thrd_start_t func, void *arg)` for `CreateThread()` now? I mean, neither do I have the StackSize, nor any CreationFlags.

I think I am going wrong somewhere, but I do not know where. If I manage to understand this piece, I can do the rest of the header myself.I know there are solutions out there, but I want to understand this.

Comment: *Why* do you want to implement your own *pthreads* on top of windows API? This has already been done (but is probably some more work than just a header) and works well e.g. in my *MinGW* installation. For C11 threads, you could [use this header](https://github.com/jtsiomb/c11threads/blob/master/c11threads.h) anywhere *pthreads* are available.

Comment: Ok I explained this poorly: I do not want to implement pthreads on windows. I want to use C11 threads on windows and replace the pthreads with windows pendant

Comment: You might find some inspiration in an [existing implementation](https://locklessinc.com/downloads/winpthreads.h). `Stacksize 0` stands for using the default as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: This boils down to basically the same problem. The C11 threading API is close enough to POSIX threads, so a single header file with just a few inline adapters and typedefs can work. This won't work for the winapi, it's *very* different. Just use a library providing *pthreads* on windows and you're done. *MinGW* comes with one, or you could [look here](https://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/)

Comment: I don't want to make an answer as I don't think an answer can do more than simply collate the points made by a few of these comments. I wish to re-inforce that there are already pthread implementations for windows that wrap the native win api. However, while I havn't used mingw it was my impression that it used its own toolchain and runtime library which -
 if so - makes it undesirable if OP prefers to use Visual Studio. Also, if OPs purpose is only to create a thread, the inclusion of an entire pthreads implementation seems a bit overkill if we could, simply, wrap 1 call to CreateThread.

Comment: never used it, but there's https://github.com/tinycthread/tinycthread and https://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/tree/include/c11

Comment: @ChrisBecke I don't know which pthread library mingw uses, but for the core runtime, it links the old `msvcrt.dll`. Some (including microsoft) consider this *wrong* and it has the drawback of a standard library only conforming to C89, but the advantage is to get binaries that don't need to bundle a runtime.

Comment: Don't use `CreateThread` is you are using the CRT in the thread function. Use `_beginthreadex` instead, as explained in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453.aspx).